# Alternative for exchange inbox with many users

Tags: email, microsoft-exchange

Currently we use a managed Exchange 2019 inbox to manage all our mail traffic. We are around 7 people, all working with the same Exchange inbox.

The more people we are, the more desync issues we have. For example, an email I moved to a folder is moved back when another user syncs at the same time, categorizing emails (we use that a lot) gets reset about 3-4 times until the tag actually stays in place.

TLDR: It's a mess to use Exchange with multiple people in the same inbox.

I look for an alternative solution that doesn't have that sync issues and multiple people (scaleable) can work on the same inbox (email address).

I looked into Zendesk etc. but we don't actually need a full customer service application, only a reliable email like service.

Also 50€ per person is way above the amount we would like to spend. 5-10€ per user would be acceptable, but above that it doesn't make much sense.